# Why equating $hf$ by $pc$ in case of photon?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, photons

I'm an electrical engineer and this my first course about modern physics.

While studying the relativistic energy relation  We concluded that the total energy of a particle $(E)$ is equal to it's $(K.E)$ $+$ rest mass energy written in that way

\begin{gather*} E=K.E+E_{0}\end{gather*}

Where $E_{0}$ is the rest mass energy and $E$ is the total energy

but in case of light ,, the light doesn't have  rest mass energy and it's total energy is equal to
\begin{gather*}E=pc\end{gather*}
and we have said before that the total energy of is equal to kinetic + rest mass energy,, then this should mean that the light while propagating has a kinetic energy equal to $pc$ .

but in Planck theory Planck has concluded that the electromagnetic energy of a photon is equal to
\begin{gather*}E=hf\end{gather*}

My question is as follow :

Why in all cases we equate this energies together like we say that $hf=pc$? ,,like in Compton effect

Why we equate these energies together and we know they are of different types ? and how did we know that these energies must be equal to each other ?

Answer (score 3):

Planck *guessed* that there was a smallest energy fluctuation (a *quantum*) of light that would obey $E=hf$.$^\dagger$

Since classically all light obeys $E=pc$, it's natural to suppose this relationship continues to be true for quanta of light as well.

Then -- the real justification -- *assuming* that light is made of quanta with $E=hf$ that also obey the classically expected relationship $E=pc$ led to an enormous number of *correct experimental predictions.* For example, $E=hf$ is used to derive the Planck spectrum. And assigning photons a momentum $p=hf/c$ leads to conservation of momentum in Compton scattering.

In other words, I would say that the statement that an individual photon obeys $E=hf$ and $E=pc$ is not something that can be *derived* (at least not from classical physics), but rather a hypothesis that has turned out to be enormously powerful in explaining experiments and as a basis for more complex theories.

---

$^\dagger$ Well, technically, he guessed that there was a restriction on the energy of oscillators in the walls of a cavity containing the light, but I've phrased it in a more modern way of understanding.

Comment: so when equating the two energies by each other $hf=pc$ 

such that $E=pc$ form relativity and $E=hf$ from Planck theory,, this is only a hypothesis and there is no explanation or proof from where it came from ?

because what in my Mind is that why we didn't say that there is a new total energy equal to the two energies together like if we say 

$E=hf+pc$

Comment: @Mans We never have a proof of where it comes from. It comes from looking at the phenomena and trying to capture how they work in math. But the phenomena are in control: we have no unquestionable axioms.

Comment: @JohnDoty 

so the only explanation of Why we equate  $hf$ by $pc$ is that :

it's just a phenomena and by assuming that the two terms are equal it explained a lot of phenomenon  ?

Comment: @Mans Yes. You can't derive $E=hf$ from classical physics. You can derive $E=pc$ within the context of classical physics, but a priori it could have been that $E=pc$ gets corrected in quantum physics. However, it's a kind of "minimal" guess to assume $E=hf$ for quanta while extrapolating that the classical formula $E=pc$ continues to hold for photons, and this minimal guess works. Physics is not math; at the end of the day the fundamental principles are justified because they make predictions that agree with experiment.

Comment: @Andrew And even the classical theory for which $E=pc$ was a consequence of the experimental results (Coulomb, Faraday, ...).

Comment: @JohnDoty This me just quibbling since I agree with your main point, but the distinction I would make is that $E=pc$ for electromagnetic radiation "falls out" of Maxwell's equations as a prediction, which was then verified. (Of course, Maxwell would never have written down his equations in the first place without experimental input from Faraday and others). In other words, $E=pc$ is a derivable consequence of other foundational facts of electromagnetism. Whereas $E=hf$ doesn't follow from anything in classical physics. It's a logically new and independent assertion.

Comment: @Andrew 

I just want to make sure that I understand you correctly.

When we said that $hf=pc$ for a photon, we had no proof for it, it's just an experiment that have proved that these two quantities are equal to each other, Am I right ?

Comment: @Andrew My point is that Maxwell's equations are not "foundational" facts. The experimental results are the foundations.

Comment: @Mans Not just one experiment. Many, many experiments demonstrate it, and many, many technologies depend on it.

Comment: @JohnDoty I disagree in the sense that it's important for a theory to make a finite number of assumptions, then everything else the theory says should be a derivable consequence (ie, a *prediction*) that logically follow from those assumptions. In that sense, I think Maxwell's equations absolutely *are* foundational to electromagnetism. If the theory were defined by the phenomena, then it would never make any predictions and would have only trivial scientific content. (Of course, a theory can make *wrong* predictions -- phenomena are the ultimate arbiter on whether a theory is good or not :))

Comment: @Andrew Maxwell's equations capture a wide range of phenomena  with a small number of assumptions, and that's incredibly useful. Still, the phenomena are the foundation upon which they rest.

Comment: @Mans Well, it depends on what you mean by "proof". For me, a "proof" is a series of logically correct statements that connect some assumptions to a conclusion. Within quantum field theory, you can "prove" $hf=pc$. But this is cheating since we developed QFT so $hf=pc$ would fall out as a consequence. What I would say is that you cannot logically conclude $hf=pc$ from anything in classical physics. However, you can assume it, and then you find that it leads to many correct predictions of experimental results.